# Using DOM in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a functional code for searching on Google Books. Here it is:

```js
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var cover, title, author;

function handleResponse(response) {
  for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
    var item = response.items[i];
    // Create elements
    figure = document.createElement("figure");
    img = document.createElement("img");
    figcap = document.createElement("figcaption");
    // Receive data from JSON
    try {
      cover = item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
      title = item.volumeInfo.title;
      author = item.volumeInfo.authors;
    } catch (error) {
      continue;
    } finally {
      // Assign values to elements and insert them in HTML
      result.appendChild(figure);
      img.src = cover;
      figure.appendChild(img);
      figcap.innerHTML += `${title}<br>${author}`;
      figure.appendChild(figcap);
    }
  }
}
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  result.innerHTML = "";
  search = document.getElementById("search").value;
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${search}&callback=handleResponse`;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#Adicionar form {
  width: 100%;
}

#Adicionar form input {
  overflow: visible;
  outline: 0;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background-color: #dee3e6;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0.5px solid #D1D9E6;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px #b8b9be, inset -3px -3px 7px #ffffff;
}

#result {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#result figure {
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<section id="Adicionar">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Pesquise por título, autor, editora, lançamento, ISBN..." />
    <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
  </form>
  <div id="result"></div>
</section>
```

For several reasons I would like to replicate this research in Python.
I'm not very familiar with the language yet, so I've been looking for how to use `getElementById`, `createElement` and `appendChild` but I didn't find anything useful. Is there a package that facilitates this?

Or is there an even more useful way to display Python book search results than using what I'm asking for?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't missed [the concept](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)?

Comment: There is `pyquery` - a library that replicates most of jQuery's API and should feel familiar if you have ever worked with jQuery. It's also easier to handle than using raw DOM methods for DOM manipulation. https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/

Comment: You want to look up web scraping. See beautiful soup or scrapy

Comment: @Teemu, I am sure. I am about to use Python because I have to work with database, so I wonder if it is possible to use Python for this stuff too.

Comment: @Tomalak, I really appreciate, I am going to look about it.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser, I really appreciate, I am going to look about it.